# Magento 2 product changes do not update

Tags: products, reindex, magento-2.1.4

No change in the products take effect on the frontend, unless I reindex and clear the cache. Is that normal?

When my website was first up live, I don't remember having an issue like this.

Does anybody know anything about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reindex the Indexing from terminal :

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

> Or You can disable cache and Change index mode to "Update on save"
>   then make your changes for product and check!

Comment: Thank you, I had the option "Update on Schedule" on the Indexing menu and I changed it back. Do you know by chance why when you select the "Update on Save" has a red background - like it's not recommended, whereas the "Update on Schedule" has a green one? It would help me understand Magento's functionality better.